# After jquery hide then show, width of width:auto elements is smaller than normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display a list of information, and it works normally, however when I hide the div containing the list and then show it again, the width of the elements with the "width: auto" styling are  being re sized and the new size is too small:

**Before hide:**

[image]

**After Hide:**

[image]

My php generating the elements looks like this:

```
<div displayitem='true'>
    <table>
        <?php
            foreach($aExistingChangeDetailsData['customers'] as $aCustomer){
                ?><tr><td><li style='width:auto;'><?php echo $aCustomer['sCustomerName']; ?></li></td></tr><?php
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

and my jquery is simply:

```
function expandSection() {
    $("div.cd-content").show("slow");
}

function collapseSection() {
    $("div.cd-content").hide("slow");
}
```

I'm guessing the issue is due to the re sizing nature of the slide animation, is there any simple way to keep the width of width:auto elements after the hide so they are restored to the proper size?

Edit:
It seems to be decreasing the width by exactly 5 for every element.

Comment: Show us a live version of the HTML/CSS/JS, maybe a jsFiddle. It's hard to guess at the problem without seeing it in action and fiddling with the code. The PHP shouldn't have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: try to use fadeIn and fadeOut istead of show and hide respectively, cause `hide()` changes width of element to zero, but `fadeOut()` changes attribute `opacity` and doesn't `width`

Comment: @philtune I tried to replicate it on a fiddle and I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` istead of `show` and `hide` respectively, cause `hide()` changes width of element to zero, but `fadeOut()` changes attribute `opacity` and doesn't `width`

Comment: Thanks! Works great! I also added "fast" to the fades so that it better matches the hide/show animation wise.

Answer (score 1):

your inline width: auto styling is only being set once on first render, you can also set it after events fire:

```
function expandSection() {
    $("div.cd-content").show("slow").css("width", "auto");

}

function collapseSection() {
    $("div.cd-content").hide("slow");
}
```

Comment: Very good idea, but it did not work. I might have to explore this later so I can get the slide back.

Comment: sorry I was using jquery width() wrongly, changed my answer to use .css

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify which element(s) width is set to 0 after using `.hide()`.

Then before calling `.hide()` fetch the original widths i.e. example below

```
const parentWidth = $('.slick-track').css('width');
const childWidth = $('.js-slide').css('width');
```

The call `.hide()` to hide the element block (as per desired functionality)

On calling .show(), set the width of the affected element(s) back to its original widths, i.e.

```
//fix collapse width
$('.slick-track').css('width', parentWidth);
$('.js-slide').css('width', childWidth);
```

This will do it, the element width(s) will be restored to its original width